# SABER SI UNA VARIABLE EXISTE

Tags: c#

Quiero saber si una variable ya a sido creada.
tengo un IF que instancia una clase y se inicializa una variable.

```
if (nivel == "1")
{
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
HtmlGenericControl a = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
tree2.Controls.Add(li);
a.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
a.InnerHtml = titulo;  //nivel 1
li.Controls.Add(a);
}
```

En este caso quiero saber si la variable li ya fue creada.
Algo asi :

```
if(exists li){
 if (nivel == "2")
  {
     HtmlGenericControl ul2 = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
     li.Controls.Add(ul2);
     HtmlGenericControl li2 = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
     ul2.Controls.Add(li2);
     HtmlGenericControl a2 = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
     a2.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
     a2.InnerHtml = nombre;
     li2.Controls.Add(a2);
     HtmlGenericControl ul3 = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
     li2.Controls.Add(ul3);
   }
}
```

Dado que esa variable solo se crea en tiempo de ejecución, necesito hacer esa condición.

Comment: La variable li solo vive adentro de ese if. No podes averiguar afuera si ya existe o no. Como te comente en tu pregunta anterior, tu problema viene por otro lado. Es lo que llamamos un problema A->B.. queres solucionar algo que pensas que esta bien, pero en realidad tu planteo es incorrecto.

Comment: en C# no puedes utilizar una variable si no ha sido declarada antes. El compilador te lanzará un error. Como gbianchi te ha dicho, tu planteamiento es incorrecto. Deberás re-plantear tu solución.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las variables tienen un scope en el cual pueden ser accedidas, si defines la variable dentro de un bloque `if` solo sera accedida dentro de este, ahora si la defines por fuera como ser

```
HtmlGenericControl li = null;

if (nivel == "1")
{
   i = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
   //resto codigo
}
```

podrias usar la luego para preguntar si fue instanciada o no

```
if(i != null){
   //fue instanciada
}
```

Comment: Yo creo que es mejor utilizar la palabra "ámbito" en vez de "scope". La gente acostumbrada a palabras en inglés sabrá que significa scope, pero si alguien es principiante o no sabe inglés, no le quedará claro el concepto de "scope".

Comment: @Luis, hay cosas que no esta bueno traducir, se debe definir como lo que son, o me vas a decir que queda mejor "muro de fuego" en lugar de usar firewall ? se que hay que defender el idioma pero tampoco para tanto, estamos en informatica se supone que algo, aunque sea minimo, de ingles se tiene que conocer

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, pero hay cosas que se pueden decir perfectamente en español porque tiene su significado entendible. No es por defender el idioma, yo uso muchos conceptos en inglés, pero hay varios que en documentación, páginas de internet o videos se usan en español. No fue crítica a tu comentario, simplemente me pareció que decir "scope" puede no ser muy entendible para un principiante.